# WSO2 : Transforming response xml

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I would like to turn this xml response into something more easily readable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<soap:Body>
    <executeResponse xmlns="urn:GCE">
        <BusinessViewServiceexecuteOut xmlns="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common" xmlns:ns2="http://www.generixgroup.com/processus/configuration/scheduler" xmlns:ns3="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/business/service/common">
            <xmlpres>&lt;?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?> &lt;VueTable type="View" name="Table" habctr="true" total_business_row="2" nbline="400" confNbline="400" numpage="1" nbpage="1">
           &lt;JTblView name="JTblView" type="ViewObject" maxfetchsize="999" maxfetchsizeexceeded="false">
              &lt;JTblViewRow current="true" type="ViewRow" index="1" business_row_index="1">
                 &lt;Cletbl precision="6" type="VARCHAR" pk="true">
                    &lt;business_data>N&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Cletbl>
                 &lt;Codtbl precision="6" type="VARCHAR" pk="true">
                    &lt;business_data>001&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Codtbl>
                 &lt;Lib1 precision="30" type="VARCHAR">
                    &lt;business_data>Non&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Lib1>
                 &lt;Lib2 precision="30" type="VARCHAR">
                    &lt;business_data/>
                 &lt;/Lib2>
                 &lt;Lir precision="10" type="VARCHAR">
                    &lt;business_data>Non&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Lir>
              &lt;/JTblViewRow>
              &lt;JTblViewRow type="ViewRow" index="2" business_row_index="2">
                 &lt;Cletbl precision="6" type="VARCHAR" pk="true">
                    &lt;business_data>O&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Cletbl>
                 &lt;Codtbl precision="6" type="VARCHAR" pk="true">
                    &lt;business_data>001&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Codtbl>
                 &lt;Lib1 precision="30" type="VARCHAR">
                    &lt;business_data>Oui&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Lib1>
                 &lt;Lib2 precision="30" type="VARCHAR">
                    &lt;business_data/>
                 &lt;/Lib2>
                 &lt;Lir precision="10" type="VARCHAR">
                    &lt;business_data>Oui&lt;/business_data>
                 &lt;/Lir>
              &lt;/JTblViewRow>
           &lt;/JTblView>
        &lt;/VueTable></xmlpres>
        </BusinessViewServiceexecuteOut>
    </executeResponse>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

At least if I could extract what's in the value of "xmlpres", the better I could do:

```
<table><row><code></code><libelle></libelle/></row></table>
```

To then turn it into a json response but I can't see ... I just get all the output or in json stream but with everything , which is not usable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on whether you want to present the output as an XML response to the client? Or you wanted to extract a portion of it and respond that to the client? Are you trying to access only the value of `xmlpres`?

Comment: I was trying for now to extract "xmlpres" but without success.

The goal is to extract a piece of "xmlpres" to give it back as a response to the client and not to have the whole result of the WS.
The problem is that the WS returns a SOAP response but with a text value which is xml and I don't see how with apimanager it is possible to extract this xml and then browse it again as I like.

Comment: Can you try the following property mediator in the out-sequence of the API? I constructed it by looking at the response that you have shared. `<property name="OUT_MESSAGE" expression="$body//soap:Body//generic:xmlpres" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gce="urn:GCE" xmlns:generic="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common"/>`. Try this property to access the `xmlpres` element

Comment: i obtain the same response

Comment: i test this :
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="response_test">      
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml"> <format> <xmlpres>$1</xmlpres></format><args><arg xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common" xmlns:gce="urn:GCE"  expression="$body/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/gce:executeResponse/com:BusinessViewServiceexecuteOut/com:xmlpres"/></args></payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>

Comment: [2021-07-13 19:41:17,105]  INFO - LogMediator {api:readTBL1:v1.0.0} STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.

Comment: i don't understand this error ...

Comment: i test this : <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="out_test">      
<property name="OUT_MESSAGE" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common" xmlns:gce="urn:GCE"  expression="$body/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/gce:executeResponse/com:BusinessViewServiceexecuteOut/com:xmlpres"/>
</sequence>

Comment: and response here : https://pastebin.com/aEwJBqST , I don't see any transformation by mediation :(

Comment: Can you share which API Manager version you are using and the Raw response from your actual Backend (including the Content-Type header)? Share the Content-Type of the actual response. I believe this is a SOAP to REST API, correct me if wrong.

Comment: The WebService is in soap, in the wso2 api manager v4, I made a proxy that I call as a REST API.
Without WSO2 the content type is : Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Can you try something like this in the out-sequence: `<property name="XMLBody" expression="$body//soap:Body//generic:xmlpres" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gce="urn:GCE" xmlns:generic="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common" type="OM"/>
<enrich><source type="property" property="XMLBody" /><target type="body" /></enrich>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an out-mediation sequence with the following content and attach it to the respective API and try out the scenario. This is to extract the `xmlpres` content and send that as the response to the client

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="out-sequence">
    
    <!-- extract the xmlpres content and store as OM element -->
    <property name="XMLBody" 
        expression="$body//soap:Body//generic:xmlpres" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:gce="urn:GCE" 
        xmlns:generic="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common" type="OM" />
    
    <!-- pass the extracted property as response body -->
    <enrich>
        <source type="property" property="XMLBody" />
        <target type="body" />
    </enrich>
</sequence>
```

Hope this helps you to extract and send the response accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, it works !
I add this for extract the part that I want 
    <property name="XMLBody2" 
        expression="$body//VueTable"  type="OM" />
    <enrich>
        <source type="property" property="XMLBody2" />
        <target type="body" />
    </enrich>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>

It works :)

I have a question if i want to format the json as i want, what should i put? i made a test with a payload but it didn't work.

Comment: Since this is done, it is good if you can open a new question explaining the new requirement in detail.

Comment: ok :) Is there an explanation of "enrich" in the documentation?

Comment: You can find about the Enrich mediator here [Docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Enrich+Mediator)