# I can't enrich body with payload don't work

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I try to enrich body with payload but it's don't work.

I do this but it's not working , i don't understand.
I debug and my payload is ok, but when I want to analyze and transform the stream, nothing happens. I have no error, I don't see what I can do...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test-cdata">
     <log level="custom">
            <property name="======OUTSEQUENCE=======" value="CALLED"/>
        </log>
         <property expression="json-eval($.executeResponse.BusinessViewServiceexecuteOut.xmlpres)" name="jsonString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
          <script language="js"><![CDATA[
          var log = mc.getServiceLog();        
          var payload = mc.getProperty('jsonString').toString();                
          mc.setProperty('payload',payload);
          mc.setPayloadXML(
        <request>{payload}</request>);]]></script>
                     <!--   <log level="custom">
                          <property name=":: Body Inside payload::" expression="$ctx:payload"/>
                        </log>-->
            <!-- extract the xmlpres content and store as OM element -->
    <property name="XMLBody" expression="$body//request" tpe="OM" />
       <log level="custom">
                          <property name="======TEST===========" value="XMLBODY"/>
                        </log>
            <!-- pass the extracted property as response body -->
   <enrich>
        <source type="property" property="XMLBody" />
        <target type="body" />
    </enrich>
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve and what is not working with the above sequence? Further, share the WSO2 product, the version you are using, and the response you are trying to transform.

Comment: I have added some details. I have tried several things while looking for examples but I never get a result.

Comment: it's possible to transform value in string ?

Answer (score 0):

I use wso2 api manager v4 . I created a passthrough for a webservice and i try to transform the answer through mediation.
The webservice response contains this character `"&#xd;"` , and this is a problems because i don't know how to transform my response ...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<executeResponse xmlns="urn:GCE">
<BusinessViewServiceexecuteOut xmlns="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/businesscomponent/applicationmodule/common" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.generixgroup.com/processus/configuration/scheduler" 
xmlns:ns3="http://www.generix.fr/technicalframework/business/service/common">
<xmlpres>&lt;?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>&#xd;
&lt;layout_data>&#xd;
   &lt;application_data>&#xd;
      &lt;businessView>&#xd;
....
```

I had posted a request  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68346313/wso2-transforming-response-xml)!
, you helped me a lot ! it worked for a version of the WS but now the WS has evolved it does not return in the same format and that blocks me.
I try to transform "xmlpres" but without success.

Comment: How to delete html characters in my response soap ?